# Assigning coordinates to string in python?

Tags: python, coordinates, software-recommendations

Is there a specific Python package that allows me to assign coordinate location to a string?

For instance, say I have location data in the form of names, such as Burbank, CA.

Is there a module that allows me to assign coordinates to that string?

I'm new to programming so I'm not aware of all its functionality.

Comment: What GIS software are you already using?  Reviewing the documentation from its Python library would be the place to start.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to ask google maps api

```
import requests

city = 'burbank'
r = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={}".format(city))
lonlat = r.json()['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
```